# Wrap <App> in <Provider> for React Redux in React EXPO

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

How can wrap my whole app in  for react redux?

```
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        axios.post("/user/create", {
          name: user.displayName,
          email: user.email,
        });
        console.log(user.displayName, user.email);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Home"
            screenOptions={{
              headerStyle: { elevation: 0 },
              cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "#E5E5E5" },
            }}>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}></Tab.Screen>
            <Tab.Screen name="News" component={NewsScreen}></Tab.Screen>
            <Tab.Screen name="Sessions" component={NewsScreen}></Tab.Screen>
            <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={LoginScreen}></Tab.Screen>
          </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setCurrentUser: (user) => dispatch(setCurrentUser(user)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

I have this at the moment, but I get an error

> Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options.

I think I need to wrap the whole app in  in the index.js file, but the index.js is not provided by Expo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `Provider` up a level to wrap `App` so it's ***higher in the React tree*** to provide the redux context.

It may look something like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

App

```
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
          initialRouteName="Home"
          screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: { elevation: 0 },
            cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "#E5E5E5" },
          }}>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}></Tab.Screen>
          <Tab.Screen name="News" component={NewsScreen}></Tab.Screen>
          <Tab.Screen name="Sessions" component={NewsScreen}></Tab.Screen>
          <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={LoginScreen}></Tab.Screen>
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setCurrentUser,
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: In react I would have done this, but in React Expo, it doesn't let you access that file it manages that for you

Here is the file structure.

https://prnt.sc/1qdlxzr

Comment: @KillianCode I see, then move all the component code in `App` down a level and be wrapped by the redux `Provider` in `App`. Do you need redux access in `App`, where do you access/use `setCurrentUser`?

Comment: Ah ok, let me try that.

Comment: I got it to work thank you, and I'll post how I did it now. I also spent 20 mins scratching my head because of a spelling mistake...

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up getting this to work by having 2 files

- App.js
- AppEntry.js

**App.js**

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./src/redux/store";

import AppEntry from "./src/AppEntry";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppEntry />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**AppEntry.js**

````
class AppEntry extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        axios.post("/user/create", {
          name: user.displayName,
          email: user.email,
        });
        console.log(user.displayName, user.email);

        this.props.setCurrentUser(user);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
          initialRouteName="Home"
          screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: { elevation: 0 },
            cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "#E5E5E5" },
          }}>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}></Tab.Screen>
          <Tab.Screen name="News" component={NewsScreen}></Tab.Screen>
          <Tab.Screen name="Sessions" component={NewsScreen}></Tab.Screen>
          <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={LoginScreen}></Tab.Screen>
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setCurrentUser: (user) => dispatch(setCurrentUser(user)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AppEntry);```
````

Comment: Yes, this. I had something very similar typed up and had to step away for a moment and forgot to hit save.